# Can Azure Function be triggered by an event and then start running on schedule?

Tags: .net, azure, azure-functions, azure-triggers

Can Azure Function be triggered by a Queue message or by HTTP trigger or whatever and after the triggering it starts to run on a schedule, for example every 1 minute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not directly. You'd have to define 2 functions: one for triggering (queue / HTTP), and one timer-based, and store the state "enabled/disabled" somewhere. That can be a value in Table Storage, or you could store an App Setting enabling/disabling the timer function.

If you want to avoid doing that by hand and paying for all the invocations of disabled timer, have a look at Durable Functions, where your trigger could start an orchestration, and orchestration would schedule time recurring actions. Check [Timers in Durable Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable-functions-timers#usage-for-delay).